# Youtube bandwidth is higher than download speed

Tags: bandwidth, youtube

I have a 50mbps internet connection, when I use fast.com or ookla I get a speed of 50mbps, till now everything is normal and expected. But when I watch a YouTube video and right click on the video -> stats for nerds, I see "Connection Speed 122157 Kbps". so what is going on?

Comment: I have no information on how Youtube calculates this figure, but one thing’s for sure: It’s not a bandwidth test.

Comment: @DanielB what is the difference between "Connection Speed" and "bandwidth"?

Comment: Youtube are downloading a tiny amount of data and using that to guess your connection bandwidth, it is not accurate because it is trying not to saturate your connection for a significant percentage of time to get an accurate reading. It is just taking a stab in the dark to guess your bandwidth so that it can see if you should be able to cope with their 5Mbps HD streams.